# How to run ASP.NET Core MVC web page on localhost port 443

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and I created an ASP.NET Core MVC web app in .NET 6.0. I can change the settings to use a non https URL and it works. This page will eventually need to run on https in our QA and Production environments. I do not use IIS.

If I configure `launchsettings.json` to use https, port 443, I get an error. When I try to run the page locally using the URL `https://localhost:44337`:

> The connection for this site is not secure
> localhost sent an invalid response.
> Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

This is my `launchSettings.json` file:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "MicroGraphicsMVC": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44337",
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "sslPort": 44337
    }
  }
}
```

In my `program.cs` file, I have:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

////configure listening port
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options => options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 44337));

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

//add Dependency Injection for our objects
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMicroGraphics, MicroGraphicsRepo>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

//app.UseHttpsRedirection();
//app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

//app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

How do I get my page to run locally on https?

Edit - Mr. Wang's advice almost works. I don't get the error any more, but now my CSS/formatting doesn't work. See the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: "*I do not use IIS.*" So you are using IIS Express or something totally different?

Comment: And have you followed the instructions here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Clinux-ubuntu#trust-the-aspnet-core-https-development-certificate-on-windows-and-macos

Comment: TylerH - I am using Kestrel.

Comment: TylerH - Yes I did those steps to trust the certificate.

Comment: HTTPS requires a TLS certificate. The TLS certificate is stored on the server, and Kestrel is configured to use it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-8.0#configure-https   which means we need to configure the certificate in code or in appsetting. my test below is using certification in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated your issue in my side.

[image]

I found the issue is related to `builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel` and it would work if I comment this line. So I'm afraid it related with missing certificate.  I [found document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-8.0#bind-to-a-tcp-socket) here which demonstrate to bind a certficate, so I export the local self-signed certificate created by VS itself and put it in my app root content and have a test, and the exception disappearred.

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, serverOptions) =>
{
    serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 44337, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.UseHttps("localhost.cer");
    });
});
```

[image]

[image]

Exporting the certificate by opening mmc, add/remove Snap-ins, Certificates, Computer account, click OK. Choose certificate -> Personal -> Certificates -> double click the localhost certificate -> choose details section -> copy to file.

[image]

Comment: This almost works. I don't get the error any more but now, my CSS/formatting no longer works.

Comment: that would be another store.... is there any error in browser console window for loading CSS resources? And could you pls add more details about your issue so that we could further investigate it? By the way, is the issue only occurred after using Kestrel? Is there any configuration for restict using static files?

Comment: in my screenshoot, you can see that the css styles are still working, so we need more details for troubleshooting it.

Comment: I had to enable "UseStaticFiles();" line. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows, execute the following command in the root path of your project to trust the development certificate:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

This command ensures that the self-signed development certificate is trusted by the operating system, facilitating secure communication for your applications.

Comment: Thank You for your reply. This didn't work for me. I got a message that reads "The network is not secure."